# Call requires permissions that may be rejected by user

Tags: android, runtime-error, locationmanager

I am trying to make an application that sends location updates of a user after every five minutes. I suppose my code is working just fine but i get an error regarding the permissions that are being used by the application. I am pretty sure that i have added the permissions in the manifest file. Can someone tell me what's wrong? Here is my code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
LocationManager locationManager ;
String provider;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Getting LocationManager object
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Creating an empty criteria object
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Getting the name of the provider that meets the criteria
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

    if(provider!=null && !provider.equals("")){

        // Get the location from the given provider
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,5*60*1000,0,this);

        if(location!=null)
            onLocationChanged(location);
        else
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location can't be retrieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Provider Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Getting reference to TextView tv_longitude
    TextView tvLongitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_longitude);

    // Getting reference to TextView tv_latitude
    TextView tvLatitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_latitude);

    // Setting Current Longitude
    tvLongitude.setText("Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());

    // Setting Current Latitude
    tvLatitude.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() );
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

}

I am getting an error as **Call requires permission which may be rejected by user** in these lines-

```
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,5*60*1000,0,this);
```

My **AndroidManifest** is like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Which SDK do you use? 
If you use Marshmallow, then you need to check that the user has granted permission for every location call.

Take a look [Here.](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

You should do something like this:

```
  if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( this,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED )
{
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
        this,
        new String [] { android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION },
        LocationService.MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION
    );
}
```

request permission if you dont have it already.

check the link above for more info.

Comment: I am using android 4.2 and above.

Comment: you must be compiling using SDK 23, there is no other explanation. please check that in you App's gradle file

Comment: Yes you were right! It was compiling using SDK 23. Thanks this solved the problem.

Comment: mmm.. what is this "MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION " ?

Comment: a constant int, for the response.

Comment: Sorry but it is written "this solved the problem" but not how?? What file should be modified and how?

Answer (score 15):

Try my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /* GPS Constant Permission */
    private static final int MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 11;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 12;

    /* Position */
    private static final int MINIMUM_TIME = 10000;  // 10s
    private static final int MINIMUM_DISTANCE = 50; // 50m

    /* GPS */
    private String mProviderName;
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private LocationListener mLocationListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Get the best provider between gps, network and passive
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        mProviderName = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // API 23: we have to check if ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and/or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission are granted
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // No one provider activated: prompt GPS
            if (mProviderName == null || mProviderName.equals("")) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
            }

            // At least one provider activated. Get the coordinates
            switch (mProviderName) {
                case "passive":
                    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(mProviderName, MINIMUM_TIME, MINIMUM_DISTANCE, this);
                    Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(mProviderName);
                    break;

                case "network":
                    break;

                case "gps":
                    break;

            }

        // One or both permissions are denied.
        } else {

            // The ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION is denied, then I request it and manage the result in
            // onRequestPermissionsResult() using the constant MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
            }
            // The ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is denied, then I request it and manage the result in
            // onRequestPermissionsResult() using the constant MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION },
                        MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission was granted
                } else {
                    // permission denied
                }
                break;

            case MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission was granted
                } else {
                    // permission denied
                }
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Source: [LINK](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: You could call `requestPermission` just once passing both the permissions within the array,

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula I will try :) Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: It might actually not make any difference because of [Permission groups](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#perm-groups). When you get permission for `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`, you automatically get for `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`, since they belong to the same group (`LOCATION`). See more about this here: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
   Toast.makeText(YourService.this, "First enable LOCATION ACCESS in settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   return;
}
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 100, 1, listener);
```

Comment: This is right, for any reason android studio raises an error if you don't put this exact code when requesting location, even if you manage the permissions in a other custom way.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the bunch of steps you need to perform to fix this

**Main Activity .java**

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
 android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
 || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) 
 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {         
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates
 (locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,5*60*1000,0,this);
}//end of if
```

Now you also need to update your **build.gradle**

```
dependencies{
 ------------- //your pre-generated code
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
}
```

[this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) is what Android.Developers say about it.

And **don't forget to give permissions from application settings** *if you're using an emulator because it may not prompt for such*