# LocationServices.FusedLocationApi... error

Tags: java, android, annotations, location, location-services

in AS this line appears underlined:

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
```

Below the  code fragment

```
    package com.websmithing.gpstracker;

    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.util.Log;

    import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
    import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
    import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.net.URLEncoder;
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.TimeZone;

    //import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;

    public class LocationService extends Service implements
            GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
            GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
            LocationListener {

        private static final String TAG = "LocationService";

        // use the websmithing defaultUploadWebsite for testing and then check your
        // location with your browser here: https://www.websmithing.com/gpstracker/displaymap.php
        private String defaultUploadWebsite;

        private boolean currentlyProcessingLocation = false;
        private LocationRequest locationRequest;
        private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            defaultUploadWebsite = getString(R.string.default_upload_website);
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            // if we are currently trying to get a location and the alarm manager has called this again,
            // no need to start processing a new location.
            if (!currentlyProcessingLocation) {
                currentlyProcessingLocation = true;
                startTracking();
            }

            return START_NOT_STICKY;
        }

        private void startTracking() {
            Log.d(TAG, "startTracking");

            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

                googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                        .build();

                if (!googleApiClient.isConnected() || !googleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                    googleApiClient.connect();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "unable to connect to google play services.");
            }
        }

        protected void sendLocationDataToWebsite(Location location) {
            // formatted for mysql datetime format
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
            Date date = new Date(location.getTime());

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.websmithing.gpstracker.prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

            float totalDistanceInMeters = sharedPreferences.getFloat("totalDistanceInMeters", 0f);

            boolean firstTimeGettingPosition = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("firstTimeGettingPosition", true);

            if (firstTimeGettingPosition) {
                editor.putBoolean("firstTimeGettingPosition", false);
            } else {
                Location previousLocation = new Location("");
                previousLocation.setLatitude(sharedPreferences.getFloat("previousLatitude", 0f));
                previousLocation.setLongitude(sharedPreferences.getFloat("previousLongitude", 0f));

                float distance = location.distanceTo(previousLocation);
                totalDistanceInMeters += distance;
                editor.putFloat("totalDistanceInMeters", totalDistanceInMeters);
            }

            editor.putFloat("previousLatitude", (float)location.getLatitude());
            editor.putFloat("previousLongitude", (float)location.getLongitude());
            editor.apply();

            final RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
            requestParams.put("latitude", Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
            requestParams.put("longitude", Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));

            Double speedInMilesPerHour = location.getSpeed()* 2.2369;
            requestParams.put("speed",  Integer.toString(speedInMilesPerHour.intValue()));

            try {
                requestParams.put("date", URLEncoder.encode(dateFormat.format(date), "UTF-8"));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {}

            requestParams.put("locationmethod", location.getProvider());

            if (totalDistanceInMeters > 0) {
                requestParams.put("distance", String.format("%.1f", totalDistanceInMeters / 1609)); // in miles,
            } else {
                requestParams.put("distance", "0.0"); // in miles
            }

            requestParams.put("username", sharedPreferences.getString("userName", ""));
            requestParams.put("phonenumber", sharedPreferences.getString("appID", "")); // uuid
            requestParams.put("sessionid", sharedPreferences.getString("sessionID", "")); // uuid

            Double accuracyInFeet = location.getAccuracy()* 3.28;
            requestParams.put("accuracy",  Integer.toString(accuracyInFeet.intValue()));

            Double altitudeInFeet = location.getAltitude() * 3.28;
            requestParams.put("extrainfo",  Integer.toString(altitudeInFeet.intValue()));

            requestParams.put("eventtype", "android");

            Float direction = location.getBearing();
            requestParams.put("direction",  Integer.toString(direction.intValue()));

            final String uploadWebsite = sharedPreferences.getString("defaultUploadWebsite", defaultUploadWebsite);

            LoopjHttpClient.get(uploadWebsite, requestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                    LoopjHttpClient.debugLoopJ(TAG, "sendLocationDataToWebsite - success", uploadWebsite, requestParams, responseBody, headers, statusCode, null);
                    stopSelf();
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
                    LoopjHttpClient.debugLoopJ(TAG, "sendLocationDataToWebsite - failure", uploadWebsite, requestParams, errorResponse, headers, statusCode, e);
                    stopSelf();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "position: " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude() + " accuracy: " + location.getAccuracy());

                // we have our desired accuracy of 500 meters so lets quit this service,
                // onDestroy will be called and stop our location uodates
                if (location.getAccuracy() < 500.0f) {
                    stopLocationUpdates();
                    sendLocationDataToWebsite(location);
                }
            }
        }

        private void stopLocationUpdates() {
            if (googleApiClient != null && googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                googleApiClient.disconnect();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the
         * client finishes successfully. At this point, you can
         * request the current location or start periodic updates
         */
        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnected");

            locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setInterval(1000); // milliseconds
            locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000); // the fastest rate in milliseconds at which your app can handle location updates
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

// this line of error   
     LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed");

            stopLocationUpdates();
            stopSelf();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
            Log.e(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has been suspend");
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi… error` which error

Comment: Please add your error log here...

Comment: this line appears underlined

LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates (googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);

Comment: @AndresArango share image what error you are getting

Comment: Ok, this is image https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU0hb.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

press `Alt-Enter`, and look for a quick-fix that adds a `@SuppressLint` annotation, to tell Lint to stop complaining about this issue.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {  android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION  },
                                                LocationService.MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION );
}
```

you can check [this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33070595/2826147)

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33327984/call-requires-permissions-that-may-be-rejected-by-user

Comment: Sorry, I'm a novice in this, where I put the lines that tell me, i put in activitymain, but show me this https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cd2Z.jpg

Comment: Use alt+enter that will import required thing and inform if any error